# Date Pipe Angular it is not able to show only Month and Year it shows date, month and year

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date-pipe

I am using bootstrap input date and saving a new Date from dialog box.
But when I want to show I want only to show the month and year.
I have added the pipe to show month and year but it shows month, year and date.

```
<input  name="startdate" [ngModel]="data.career.startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'"
                 (ngModelChange)="data.career.startDate = $event" type="date" class="form-control-sm">
```

This is how I save data.

And this is how I try to show date.

```
<input type="date" [ngModel]="subCategory.startDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'" class="form-control-sm" readonly>
```

I tried here to write the pipe `yyyy-MM` but it didn't work.

I don't want to have the `matpicker` from angular material.
It is possible only to show month and year ?
Here is the current photo what I see.
And only to show in format number not month as string   .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="date">` will always show local date format in supported browsers. To show formatted date, use `<input type="text">`

Comment: I never thought about that.
Thank you it works.
How it is possible in dialog box only to ask for month and year without day.
Can u help me on that ?
@kvetis

Comment: You can use `input type="month"` if you have control of the browser the appliaction is used in. It is only supported in [some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Yeah to shame that for some browsers that doesnt work.